# in my trainer, a thread doesn't stop when the condition is met

Tags: python, multithreading

i am making a Alan Wake remaster trainer in python with customtkinter and pymem, everything worked fine until i started adding threading.

in the window there are checkboxes that, when active, starts setting a value to the batteries or revolver ammo to simulate a NOP instruction, but when that happens the rest of the program freezes, i solved that by adding threads, the thing is, when you activate both batteries and revolver checkboxes, and uncheck the battery one, it doesn't stop doing the battery cheat.

```
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import *
from customtkinter import *
import threading

class Trainer:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.root = CTk()
        self.root.title("Alan Wake Remaster Trainer")
        set_appearance_mode("dark")
        self.root.geometry("400x600")
        self.root.resizable(0,0)
    
        self.mf = CTkFrame(master=self.root)
        self.mf.pack(fill="both", expand= True)
    
        self.bc_var = IntVar()
        self.rv_var = IntVar()
        
        self.battery_checkbox = CTkCheckBox(master=self.mf,text="Unlimited Batteries",variable=self.bc_var,command=self.check)
        self.battery_checkbox.pack()
        self.battery_checkbox.place(x=140,y=50)
        
        self.revolver_checkbox = CTkCheckBox(master=self.mf, text="Unlimited Revolver Ammo", variable=self.rv_var,command=self.check)
        self.revolver_checkbox.pack()
        self.revolver_checkbox.place(x=140,y=80)

        self.keep_running = True
    
    def check(self):
        if self.bc_var.get() == 1:
            self.keep_running = True
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.write_bat)
            t.start()
        if self.rv_var.get() == 1:
            self.keep_running = True
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.write_rev)
            t1.start()
        elif self.bc_var.get() == 0:
            self.keep_running = False
        elif self.rv_var.get() == 0:
            self.keep_running == False
            
    
        
    
    def write_bat(self):
        while self.keep_running:
            Pymem.write_int(mem, self.getpointer(module_bat + 0x00AE69D0, offsets_bat), 20)
        
    def write_rev(self):
        while self.keep_running:
            Pymem.write_int(mem, self.getpointer(module_rev + 0x0000027C, offsets_rev), 42)
    
    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
    
    def getpointer(self,base,offsets):
        addr = mem.read_int(base)
        for offset in offsets:
            if offset != offsets[-1]:
                addr = mem.read_int(addr + offset)
        addr = addr + offsets[-1]
        return addr
 

mem = Pymem("Game_f_x64_EOS.exe")
module_bat = module_from_name(mem.process_handle, "Game_f_x64_EOS.exe").lpBaseOfDll
module_rev = module_from_name(mem.process_handle, "fmod.dll").lpBaseOfDll
offsets_bat = [0x50,0x128,0x10,0x48,0xD0,0x144]
offsets_rev = [0xC0,0x68,0x10,0xE0,0x148]

app = Trainer()
app.run()
```

what im trying to explain is that the battery thread doesn't stop when the checkbox is unmarked and the revolver ammo is.

i tried separating the threads with another check function but the same happens, and tried other stuff but it just breaks.

my knowledge in threading is new and very limited, so if there is an alternative or a better way to do this, i'd appreciate to be told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have TWO threads but one variable (keep_running) only to control whether threads are running. Shouldn't that be two?

**Edit**: Here full working example for one thread only (you should have the command function, `self.thread` and `self.keep_running` and the thread function individual named per required thread)

```py
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Start/Stop Thread')
        self.geometry('300x300+100+100')
        self.button = tk.Button(self)
        self.button['text'] = 'Start'
        self.button['command'] = self.on_start_stop
        self.button.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.keep_running = False
        self.thread = None

    def on_start_stop(self):
        if not self.thread:
            print('starting thread')
            self.keep_running = True
            self.button['text'] = 'Stop'
            self.thread = Thread(target=self.thread_function)
            self.thread.start()
        else:
            print('trying to stop thread')
            self.keep_running = False
            # should be organized to be fast
            while self.thread.is_alive():
                sleep(0.5)
            self.thread = None
            self.button['text'] = 'Start'
            print('thread stopped')

    def thread_function(self):
        while self.keep_running:
            print("thread: hi")
            sleep(1) # sleep one second

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```